# Do i need two firewalls in security.yml in symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

I have this `security.yml` file. I want to know do i need two firewalls or one is ok.
I have read in docs that one firewall is ok and use ACL for further things.

```
firewalls:


        admin:
            pattern:      /admin(.*)
            form_login:
                provider:       fos_userbundle
                login_path:     /admin/login
                use_forward:    false
                check_path:     /admin/login_check
                failure_path:   /admin/login
                use_referer:    true
                default_target_path: /admin/dashboard                
            logout:
                path:           /admin/logout
                target:         /admin/login

            anonymous:    true

        main:
            pattern:      .*
            form-login:
                provider:       fos_userbundle
                login_path:     /login
                use_forward:    false
                check_path:     /login_check
                failure_path:   null
                default_target_path: /main 
            logout:       true
            anonymous:    true
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you will need two. One firewall protects secure pages, the second firewall allows anonymous access to open pages, which you need to open up at least for your login page (see the common pitfalls section of the [security documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#using-a-traditional-login-form)).

You will probably want to add paths to the second firewall for home, password recovery, and any other pages you want anyone to be able to access.

Comment: I think anoan pages can be done with ACL. rather than separate firewall

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood your question. You should be able to only use the 2nd firewall, and specify in ACL that the admin area requires an admin permission

Answer (score 0):

You have two entry points: `/login` and `/admin/login`. If you can make do with one, then you could merge down to one firewall.